# Pausing the Activity in Android

Tags: android

I have developed a game in android and it has some timer in it,when ever I'm playing the game if some one rings me the game is not going to paused state the time is still running in the background.what i need is when some in coming call has  arived it should display a prompt message that the game is in pause state how to achieve this..?

Comment: you need to override the `onPause()` method of the Activity

Comment: should i write the code in onPause() method...?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to override the onPause() function which is called everytime you get called you go back to the main menu or whatever. Here is a sample of the docs :

> When the system calls onPause() for your activity, it technically means your activity is still partially visible, but most often is an indication that the user is leaving the activity and it will soon enter the Stopped state.

I advise you to read [this link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html) carefully to understand the different steps in an activity life and [that link as well](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html)

Here is how to override your onPause() function :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    //Do something like pausing the timer
}
```

When the user goes back to the game, you want the timer to restart and therefore, you'll override the onResume() function :

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    //Resume the timer
}
```

Have a good day !